# How to pass default generic type in rust function?

Tags: rust

So I have a function called `cr` where I want the generic `T` to be `serde_json::Value` by default. How can I do this?

```
fn main() {
    cr()
}

fn cr<T = serde_json::Value>() {

}
```

I get this error: `cannot infer type for type parameter T declared on the function cr` while calling cr. And on cr function I get this error: `defaults for type parameters are only allowed in struct, enum, type, or trait definitions.`

Comment: I think the error message tells you your answer, you cannot have defaults for type parameters on functions. If you want to call `cr` with a `serde_json::Value` you can use the so-called 'turbofish' notation to specify it: `cr::<serde_json::Value>()`

Comment: What would it even mean to have a default type parameter on a generic function? Type parameter is ALWAYS provided by caller, either explicitly (turbofish) or implicitly, through type inference. The only situation where it wouldn't is if generic parameter isn't used in either input or output of the function.

Comment: @IvanC "The only situation where it wouldn't is if generic parameter isn't used in either input or output of the function." => That's exactly where it would be useful. A generic parameter with a trait bound could be used in the body of the function without being part of the input or output types. This could be used e.g. to allow a type to be mocked for a function's unit tests without requiring explicit generic parameters in the production code.

Answer (score 3):

As the error said you cannot use default type parameters in function signatures.
You can workaround this with a wrapper type.

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct MyDefault;
struct Custom;

pub fn main() {
    Wrapper::cr(); //~ ERROR type annotations needed
    <Wrapper>::cr();

    Wrapper::<Custom>::cr();
    <Wrapper<Custom>>::cr();
}

struct Wrapper<T = MyDefault>(PhantomData<T>);

impl<T> Wrapper<T> {
    fn cr() {
        let _: T = todo!();
    }
}
```

Inference cannot guess so it needs a type hint that can be used for substitution. For example `let x: SomeType<SubstType>` or fully qualified path `<SomeType<SubstType>>::associated_item`. Omitting the substitutions here triggers the default substitution in `SomeType`.

Comment: this would still prevent you from doing anything useful with T in cr() -- like accessing one of T's fields or calling one of T's functions -- even if they are present on the default type or on any to-be-given types.
Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: So if I understand this right: using the `<Type>` syntax is a way to disable type inference so the compiler will use a less sophisticated approach that will work when using the default generic type syntax?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the trick

```rust
type Echo<X = i32> = std::result::Result<X, String>;

fn test(x: Echo) {
    // ...
}

fn main() {
    test(Err("test".into()));
}
```

Comment: Except [it just doesn't work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=af841c9fa478bb80f4aacd6321aa01b1). It _forces_ the generic parameter, instead of _hinting_ it.